# SESSION_USER equivalent from Big Query in Data Studio reports

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-iam

We are creating dashboards for clients using data studio.
Each client should see *their* data in the dashboard, based on their login credentials. It is simple to create an authorized_view in Big Query to let certain users see certain rows of an underlying shared table. But how would one achieve to then move this into a dashboard which can be shared with each client, yet show only the individuals client in the dashboard instead of the data that was visible to the report creator?

So let's say we have a large table with a bunch of columns and one column `email` which contains the email of users. Now, we want the dashboard to show metrics for each user based on this email column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On DataStudio in the datasource schema review step, make sure the flag `USING VIEWER’S CREDENTIALS` is on. By turning it on, the query when being executed will use the viewer’s credential instead of the owner who created the report.

[image]

After you finish create proper visualization on Data Studio, final step is to share the report to eg: store managers using the share option of Data Studio which is similar to share a Google Docs. You can confidently share it with the whole organization or with the email group of eg: store managers, permission already be controlled at data level.

Read more about this topic [here](https://medium.com/7-lab/enabling-data-accessibility-at-7-eleven-with-data-studio-and-bigquery-b4570c2e1a81).

Comment: perfect answer! We have always accessed Data Studio through the BigQuery UI ("explore results in data studio") and therefore did not see this option.

Comment: Theres a great google article too on how to apply cell level auth using chained authorised views. https://medium.com/google-cloud/share-data-with-confidence-cell-level-access-controls-in-bigquery-and-data-studio-cf753fa173a4